# How do I compare salt with a generated password?

Tags: java, security, servlets, cryptography, salt

So I'm trying to compare my original password to a password that was salted. I know how to compare a hash password, I take the original password add hash to it and it works. However, I don't know how to compare the salt.

```
public static String saltPassword(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
     String salt = getSalt();
     return password + salt;
 }
public static String getSalt(){
     Random r = new SecureRandom();
     byte[] saltBytes = new byte[32];
     r.nextBytes(saltBytes);
     return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(saltBytes);
 }
```

What do I have to do to compare the original password with this?

this is literally what my assignment says,
"Compare the generated password with the stored salt and hashed password".

Comment: The answer is that you don't.  You take the password and salt and put them together.  Then you hash that.  Then you compare >>the hash<< with the hash you created previously from the original password and the same salt.

Comment: does it matter what order you do that in. I was trying something like that but I was hashing the password first and then adding the salt later

Comment: And how do I use the same salt as before since it is random everytime

Comment: See my answer.   You (typically) store the salt together with the hash of the original password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also store the salt. Salt is used to prevenet generating the same hashed password when two user choose same password. something like the following codes can be used for saving password as hashedPassord and verifying entered password.It's not complete but can be used as a sample code.

```java
private static void savePassword(String rawPassword) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    byte[] salt = getSalt();
    String hashedPassword = getHashedPassword(rawPassword, salt);
    String encodedSalt = base64Encode(salt);

    /* todo: store hashPassword and encodedSalt */
}

private static boolean verifyPassword(String rawPassword, String hashedPassword, String encodedSalt) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    return Objects.equals(hashedPassword, getHashedPassword(rawPassword, base64Decode(encodedSalt)));
}

private static String getHashedPassword(String rawPassword, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(rawPassword.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 128);
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    byte[] hash = factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    return base64Encode(hash);
}

private static byte[] getSalt() {
    Random r = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[32];
    r.nextBytes(saltBytes);
    return saltBytes;
}

private static String base64Encode(byte[] src) {
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(src);
}

private static byte[] base64Decode(String src) {
    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(src);
}
```

Comment: I would ask you the same question. does it matter what order I salt/hash in? And how do I use the same salt as before since it is random everytime.

Comment: Hi @studentguy. Generating salt should be done before hashing the password. If you store generated salt in DB, then you can use the same salt when ever you need. I added some sample code, hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank
 you that helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

> How do I compare salt with a generated password?
>
> What do I have to do to compare the original password with this?

The answer is that you don't do either if these things.

To register the original password you do the following:

1. Obtain a salt<sup>1</sup>
2. Combine the original password with the salt
3. Hash that.
4. Store the salt and the hash.

You then discard the original password.

To check that a supplied password you do the following:

1. Lookup the stored hash and the corresponding salt that were created when registering; see above.
2. Combine the supplied password and salt in the same way as above.
3. Hash that as above.
4. Compare the resulting hash with the stored hash.  If they are the same, then the supplied password is the correct password.

As you can see, you don't compare either the salt or the original password with anything.

But it is also essential that you use the same salt when generating the hashes for the original password and the password that you are checking.  If you don't, the password check doesn't work.

---

<sup>1 - The salt is just a number or string.  Ideally the salt values should be different.  The purpose of the salt is to avoid a so-called ["rainbow table" attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to recover the original password from a stolen (un-salted) password hash.  If there are (say) a million possible salt values, then the bad guys need to generate a million different rainbow tables.  Generating and storing many rainbow tables becomes impractical.</sup>

Comment: I have some code listed above. I'm hoping that will be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what i have. I would love to look up a stored password but my teacher is not doing it that way in her solution video

```
public static String saltPassword(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
     String salt = getSalt();
     return hashPassword(password + salt);
 }
 public static String getSalt(){
     Random r = new SecureRandom();
     byte[] saltBytes = new byte[32];
     r.nextBytes(saltBytes);
     return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(saltBytes);
 }
 public static String generatePassword(){
        String charSet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_-+!@#$%";
        String password = "";
        int start = 0;
        int stop = 0;
        int minLength = 8;

        for (int i = 0; i <= minLength; i++) {
                // get a random character from the chars string
                start = getRandomNumber(charSet.length());
                stop = start + 1;
                password += charSet.substring(start, stop);
        }        
        return password;
    }
    private static int getRandomNumber(int maxValue){
        double randomNumber;
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxValue);

        return (int)randomNumber;
    }
    public static String hashPassword(String password)throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(password.getBytes());
        byte[] mdArray = md.digest();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(mdArray.length * 2);
        for (byte b : mdArray){
            int v = b & 0xff;
            if(v < 16){
                sb.append('0');
            }
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(v));
        }
        return sb.toString();   
    }
```

Then to create it I am going to go

```
    String newPassword = PasswordUtil.generatePassword();
    String hashedPassword = "";
    String saltedPassword = "";

try{
            hashedPassword = PasswordUtil.hashPassword(newPassword);
        }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            System.out.println();
        }
        try{
            saltedPassword = PasswordUtil.saltPassword(hashedPassword);
        }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println();
        }
```

What happens next?

this is the hashed password:

```
50f99d2a635cc9bac7e001506789b55a7c603d93c89d362cc5d95ab257fc2666
```

and this is the hash with the salt

```
e954fbc2309cc359cd603effb6d0644947a3253110ad6c3b2416dd49168331a3
```

Comment: Generating a new random salt each time and not storing it with the hash does not work.  It is likely that you have *misunderstood* how this is supposed to work.  I note that none of the instructor's code in your self-answer is actually storing anything.  I'm inclined to think that the instructor has got this wrong ....

Comment: So if a random salt is not comparable then why store it at all?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I didn't say anything about salts being comparable.

Comment: What I said is that the same salt must be using when generating the hash of the original password and the hash of the password that you want to check.  That is why you either have to store the original salt ... or generate the salt from some other (constant) information (e.g. the user's account name)

Comment: If a random salt is not useable for comparison. how would someone be able to login to a website with it? Why would you use a random generated password? I'm just confused why my book is showing me something that doesn't have a functional use.

Comment: You don't compare salts.  I don't know why you keep on bringing this up.

Comment: Would you store the instance of the randomly generated salt to have reference to later?

Comment: The randomly generated password is just an example.

Comment: *Would you store the instance of the randomly generated salt to have reference to later?* - Because that is the way that salts work.  Please read the procedure in my answer carefully ... and try to understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it

Comment: (What I don't understand is the full context of the assignment you are trying to do.  It is not clear to me whether there is something about the assignment that you have misunderstood OR there is a mistake in the assignment and / or the associated teaching material.)

Comment: Do you think I could show you what I'm doing? Skype or something?

Comment: Sorry, no.  I suggest you discuss this with the instructor.  She is the best person to explain her solution to you.